# Unbind loops in React

Tags: reactjs, components, nested-loops

My problem is the following. In React App, I have a sequence of nested loops like these:
`

```
 {Object.entries(data)?.map((log) => {
              const [item1, item2] = log ?? [];
              return (
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <p>{item1}</p>
                  </div>

                  {Object.entries(item2)?.map((itemObj) => {
                    const [item2a, item3] = itemObj ?? [];
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <p>{item2a}</p>

                        {Object.entries(item3)?.map((item3Obj) => {
                          const [item3b, item4] =item3Obj ?? [];
                          return (
                            <div>
                              <p>{item3b}</p>
                            </div>
                          );
                        })}
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              );
            })}
```

`

Hello everyone!!
I need to create components for each element but I don't know how to do it without breaking the nested loops.

Comment: What do you mean by "without breaking the nested loops"? What's your expected output?

Comment: Post your `data` structure also

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.